# CSS absolute child behind its parent

Tags: css

**CSS only**

I'd like to have my absolute positioned `div` behind it's (relative) parent,
**but** still stay on top of it's parent siblings.
So using a negative `z-index` value won't help here...

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/naomipol12/w6h6qgdy/1/) is actually the opposite of what I'm looking for:
The parent div (on the left) should be on top of green child div and the sibling div (on the right) should be behind it.

Any idea here?

Comment: check my answer below. let me know if it works

Answer (score 3):

see here > **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6h6qgdy/2/)**

i also suggest that you add a different class to the `.container` that has `.inner` in it

like : `<div class="container parent">` and then in CSS `.parent ~ *{z-index:-2}` so you are sure all it's siblings have `z-index:-2`

or snippet below :

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;

}

.inner {
  top: 5px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
}
.container:not(:first-child) {
  z-index:-2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: It does work, but I have 2 problems with this: 1. The selector for other elements is very specific to this example (doesn't work in my code) 2. When setting the z-index to a negative one I loose the hover ability (I do need)

Comment: well...i need more code from you if you want me to make a 100% working answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child selector` to target `two different parent div` of same class `.container`, as below,

```css
.container:nth-child(1){
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.inner {
  top: 5px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
}
.container:nth-child(2){
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index:-2;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: why use the same styles 2 times ? just use the styles that all the divs with class `container ` have in common only one time and then the specific styles for different `container` divs. for example if both have `background-color:red` just write it one time `.container{background-color:red` } not 2 times.

Comment: @MihaiT yes you are right, my main point was that you can make use on nth-child selector and can style two div with same class name but different css properties. Thus it become easy by seeing properties of both div what they performing. And while using nth-child selector user has to define css properties for each selected element.

Comment: yes. you can use `nth-child` . but in the same time you can style `.container { background:red;position:absolute;width:50px} ` etc and for example write `.container:nth-child(2) { background:blue;}` ; `.container:nth-child(5) { background: yellow;}`  etc. and just change the style that is specific for that `nth-child`

Comment: @MihaiT yes can do that too. Both option works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to give z-index property to it. The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

```
.inner {
  top: 5px;
  left: -10px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: -10px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
```

You can see the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/w6h6qgdy/3/)

Comment: the first red box ( on the left ; the parent of inner ) must be on top of the green box ( inner )